# GARCH calibration with overlapping time intervals

Tags: volatility, garch

In constructing a GARCH(1,1) model over a time length $\delta$, I am considering the following procedure. The purpose of this procedure is to give more training (calibrating) samples than non-overlapping consecutive samples.
\begin{align}
\nu(k\delta,(k+1)\delta) &= \omega+\alpha r((k-1)\delta,k\delta)^2+\beta \nu((k-1)\delta,k\delta) \\
\nu\big((k+0.5)\delta,(k+1.5)\delta\big) &= \omega+\alpha\,r\big((k-0.5)\delta,(k+0.5)\delta\big)^2+\beta\,\nu\big((k-0.5)\delta,(k+0.5)\delta\big)
\end{align}
for $k\in \bf \bar{Z^-}$, where $\nu(s,t)$ stands for the variance between time $s$ and $t$, $r(s,t)$ the return between $s$ and $t$. I calibrate the parameter tuple $(\omega, \alpha, \beta)$ simultaneously with the above equations for overlapping time intervals.

I use the following method to estimate the parameters. Define $\displaystyle l(k):=\ln v(k\delta,(k+1)\delta)+\frac{r(k\delta,(k+1)\delta)^2}{v(k\delta,(k+1)\delta))}$ and
$$-2\,\text{Log-Likelihood}=(k_1+k_2)\ln(2\pi)+\sum_{k}l(k)+\sum_{k}l(k-0.5)$$
where $k_1$ and $k_2$ are the numbers of intervals in the two non-overlapping sequences of intervals. This function $-2\,\text{Log-Likelihood}$ is then minimized for over $(\omega,\alpha,\beta)$.

Is this legitimate?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish with this? :-)

Comment: @Pleb: I just added the motivation. Does it make sense to you?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is legitimate for obtaining point estimates of $\omega,\alpha,\beta$. To utilize the data fully, you would find all sets of consecutive nonoverlapping periods and use all of them in estimation. (In financial econometrics and time series analysis, *estimation* is the common word for what you mean here with *calibration*.) E.g. if you have daily data (weekdays only) and want a weekly GARCH model, you would fit it on five observation sets with time indices $(1,6,11,\dots)$, $(2,7,12,\dots)$, $\dots$, $(5,10,15,\dots)$ for the most efficient use of data. You would not take the standard errors at face value, though, since they would now be based on overlapping data.

However, I would not expect a great improvement in estimation accuracy unless the length of a single time period (a month) is a large fraction (say, 1/5 or larger) of the total sample span. E.g. if you have 240 months of daily data for a monthly GARCH model, you will not gain much from this approach. If you only had 5 months, that could have a noticeable effect. On the other hand, estimating a GARCH model given only 5 nonoverlapping periods of data (however finely sampled) would not give a reliable result anyway...

Comment: Good answer! Do you know any papers describing this procedure?

Comment: @Pleb, unfortunately, no. I have done some simulations for my own needs before but do not remember reading about it anywhere.

Comment: Okay, if you are estimating each GARCH model separately and then average the estimates, then it *sounds* like the subsampling approach usually seen for realized measures (see eg. [Zhang et al. (2005)](https://bit.ly/3wNriOb)). I have always wondered whether this approach was applicable for volatility models, but I have never found any papers about it.

Comment: @Pleb, I would estimate them jointly, but the results would probably be quite similar to averaging, at least asymptotically. However, I did not suggest to average across frequencies, though that is also an interesting possibility.

Comment: @Pleb and Richard: I have added an estimation method which minimizes the negative sum of the two log-likelihood functions of the individual non-overlapping time interval sequences. Please comment on the legitimacy of this procedure.

Comment: @Hans, I was going through my old answers and noticed this one was not accepted. Is it inadequate for your problem?